# " He is waiting downstairs" is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

If someone is waiting for me on the ground floor is it valid to say " He is waiting for me downstairs" or could we just say " He is waiting down". Does 'waiting down' has different meaning?

Comment: Downstairs is a location. "He is waiting down" is not idiomatic.

Comment: As FeliniusRex says. If you are at least one flight of stairs higher than the person concerned, yes, he is waiting for you downstairs. He could also be waiting for you **down the passage/road/lane**.

Comment: "He is waiting **below**," is idiomatic, if somewhat stiff and over-formal (to my ears).

Comment: @Canadian Yankee I think that "he is waiting below" is not idiomatic in US English, the response is likely to be "below what?" I have read it in UK sources often enough, mostly older ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"He is waiting down" is not a usual expression for anything.  If it were used, it **might** mean that the person is somehow trying to out wait another person, or some sort of deadline. It does **not** mean "He is waiting on a lower floor".

He is waiting downstairs" is a very normal and usual expression when someone is waiting on a lower flower. 'downstairs' is the most usual way of referring to the location on  a lower floor from where the speaker is.

The phrase "down the street" refers to a location some way along the street, and can be used to describe events. Similar forms such as "down the path", "down the beach", "down the hall" are common also.